# How to capture RestSharp calls to API endpoint using Fiddler

Tags: .net-5, restsharp, fiddler

I am trying to capture calls to an API endpoint sent using RestSharp (108) from a .Net 5 web application.

I am getting plenty of data recorded but nothing relating to the API endpoint.

I am running the site locally, debugging in Visual Studio 2022, I select the browser window in Fiddler, run the specific part of the application but get no API calls recorded. I tried filtering to the endpoint (global-api-sandbox.afterpay.com) but nothing.

What do I need to do to record these API calls?

I need to see what is being passed in the User-Agent header. I am setting it as per the RestSharp documentation but the testers are telling me that it isn't set correctly (it is set to "RestSharp/108.0.3.0)

Comment: Some applications ignore Windows proxy settings. So may be you have to manually configure Fiddler as proxy for the used http client library.